# How to use Cycle2 while keeping compatible with NextGen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

According to the [official FAQ](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/faq/), I can't use jQuery Cycle2 with its predecessor, [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

The problem is, I'm using this on Wordpress, and whenever I enable NextGen gallery, it enqueues the old Cycle plugin, which fails.

Is there a way to use both on the same page, or at least remove NextGen's Cycle and make a compatibility shim to make it use Cycle2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy... just replacing the "cycle"s with cycle2 in the Cycle2 source code, makes it usable with

```
$(something).cycle2({options...})
```

It's that easy - I don't see why they don't have a cycle2 namespaced version on the site for old cycle compatibility.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. Do I have to replace all "cycle"s with cycle2 or just the function names? There are things like `a.match(/^cycle(.*)/)` and `fn.cycle` in the cycle2 js file. Which ones did you replace?

Comment: I remember seeing someone post cycle2-js with this modification, somewhere.